# How to combine two Images in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

My view consists of 3 images. Image1 is the background image (Cake). Image2 is purple colour digit 6, which is drawn on top of the Image1.

[image]

Image3 is red colour digit 1.

[image]

I need a function to to combine the 6 and 1 as a single image and then convert the image to base64 string. Currently I use this function to combine the two images.

```
func combine(with: UIImage) -> UIImage {
    let baseImage = self
    let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: baseImage.size)
    print("combine rect: \(rect)")
        
    let canvasSize = CGSizeMake(rect.width, rect.height)

    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: canvasSize)
    return renderer.image { context in
        baseImage.draw(in: rect)
        with.draw(in: rect)
    }
}
```

This produces a result like this. (Cake image is hidden here)

[image]

It scale and the position is wrong. I want the combined image to match the scale and the position of the cake, So it can loaded on top of the cake image later on. What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be much appreciated.

Cake image is a SwiftUI Image.

```
 private var backgroundImage: some View {
        ZStack {
  
            KFImage(viewModel.imageUrl)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .overlay {
                    DigitView($viewModel.canvasImage)
                }

        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Why not use [ImageRenderer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/imagerenderer)

Comment: Oh thanks! I never came across that. Let me try that as well

Answer (score 0):

Based on your combine function using `UIGraphicsImageRenderer`, I changed it slightly to combine using two UIImages.

Sometime like this code below should work:

```
func combineImages(image1: UIImage, image2: UIImage) -> UIImage? {
let size = CGSize(width: image1.size.width + image2.size.width,
                  height: max(image1.size.height, image2.size.height))

let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size)

let combinedImage = renderer.image { context in
    // Draw the first image at the leftmost position
    image1.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: image1.size))
    
    // Draw the second image starting after the first image
    image2.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: image1.size.width, y: 0), size: image2.size))
}

return combinedImage
}
```

And the View code:

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Circle()
            .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
            .foregroundStyle(.red)
        Image(uiImage: combineImages(image1: UIImage(systemName: "globe")!, image2: UIImage(systemName: "airplane")!)!)
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
            .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
    }
    .padding()
}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xKVW.png)

Comment: I think you may have been voted down for confusing UIKit's UIGraphicsImageRenderer with SwiftUI's ImageRenderer. Clarifying/Fixing that in your answer would be helpful.